# Efficient way of computing dot product inside double sum in python3

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, numpy, sum, dot-product

I'm looking into how to compute as efficient as possible in python3 a dot product inside a double sum of the form:

```
import cmath
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x, [l - m for l, m in zip(r_p[j], r_p[k])])))
```

where r_np is a array of several thousand triples, and x a constant triple. Timing for a length of `N=1000` triples is about `2.4s`. The same using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
       sum_np = np.add(sum_np, np.exp(-1j * np.inner(x_np,(r_np[j] - r_np[k]))))
```

is actually slower with a runtime of about `4.0s`. I presume this is due to no big vectorizing advantage, only the short 3 dot 3 is np.dot, which is eaten up by starting N^2 of those in the loop.
However, a modest speedup over the first example I could gain by using plain python3 with map and mul:

```
from operator import mul
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * sum(map(mul,x, [l - m for l, m in zip(r_p[j], r_p[k])])))
```

with a runtime about `2.0s`

Attempts to either use an if condition to not calculate the case `j=k`, where

```
r_np[j] - r_np[k] = 0
```

and thus the dot product also becomes 0, or splitting the sum up in two to achieve the same

```
for j in range(0,N):
        for k in range(j+1,N):
    ...
for k in range(0,N):
        for j in range(k+1,N):
    ...
```

both made it even slower. So the whole thing scales with O(N^2), and I wonder if with some methods like sorting or other things one could get rid of the loops and to make it scale with O(N logN). 
The problem is that I need single digit second runtimes for a set of `N~6000` triples as I have thousands of those sums to compute. Otherwise I have to try scipy’s weave , numba, pyrex or python or go down the C path entirely…

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:**

this is how a data sample would look like:

```
# numpy arrays
x_np = np.array([0,0,1], dtype=np.float64)
N=1000
xy = np.multiply(np.subtract(np.random.rand(N,2),0.5),8)
z = np.linspace(0,40,N).reshape(N,1)
r_np = np.hstack((xy,z))

# in python format
x = (0,0,1)
r_p = r_np.tolist()
```

Comment: Could you please drop your test data in a code block so we can use it for testing ourselves?

Comment: Will `x` always be equal to `(0, 0, 1)`?

Comment: for a given sum, yes. But, that is the reason why in the end I have to compute many of those sums for different `x`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. If `x == (0, 0, 1)` you are only really using the third column of `r_np` in your calculation, so it would save some time to index only the third column rather than computing the pairwise differences over all 3, e.g. `r_np[:, None, 2] - r_np[None, :, 2]` rather than `r_np[:, None, :] - r_np[None, :, :]`. Is it always the case that one element in `x` will be 1 and the other two zeros?

Comment: I see, for the three main axes, this actually is the case. Right, it makes sense then to reduce the triple to a single for the `(x,0,0); (0,x,0) and (0,0,x)` cases.  IVlad did this already with his code by precomputing the dot product, and then only summing the 1-dim numbers. But I do also need some mixed `(x1,x2,x3)` cases, which in IVlad code is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to generate test data:

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
r_p = [(i, j, k) for i in range(10) for j in range(10) for k in range(10)]
```

On my machine, this took `2.7` seconds with your algorithm.

Then I got rid of the `zip`s and `sum`:

```
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        s = 0
        for t in range(3):
            s += x[t] * (r_p[j][t] - r_p[k][t])
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * s)
```

This brought it down to `2.4` seconds.

Then I noted that `x` is constant so:

```
x * (p - q) = x1*p1 - x1*q1 + x2*p2 - x2*q2 - ...
```

So I changed the generation code to:

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
r_p = [(x[0] * i, x[1] * j, x[2] * k) for i in range(10) for j in range(10) for k in range(10)]
```

And the algorithm to:

```
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        s = 0
        for t in range(3):
            s += r_p[j][t] - r_p[k][t]
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * s)
```

Which got me to `2.0` seconds.

Then I realized we can rewrite it as:

```
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * (sum(r_p[j]) - sum(r_p[k])))
```

Which, surprisingly, got me to `1.1` seconds, which I can't really explain - maybe some caching going on?

Anyway, caching or not, you can precompute the sums of your triples and then you won't have to rely on the caching mechanism. I did that:

```
sums = [sum(a) for a in r_p]

sum_p = 0
N = len(r_p)
start = time.clock()
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * (sums[j] - sums[k]))
```

Which got me to `0.73` seconds.

I hope this is good enough!

**Update:**

Here's one around `0.01` seconds with a single for loop. It seems mathematically sound, but it's giving slightly different results, which I'm guessing is due to precision issues. I'm not sure how to fix those, but I thought I'd post it in case you can live with the precision issues or someone knows how to fix them.

Considering I'm using fewer `exp` calls than your initial code however, consider that maybe this is actually the more correct version, and your initial approach is the one with precision issues.

```
sums = [sum(a) for a in r_p]
e_denom = sum([cmath.exp(1j * p) for p in sums])
sum_p = 0
N = len(r_p)
start = time.clock()
for j in range(0,N):
    sum_p += e_denom * cmath.exp(-1j * sums[j])

print(sum_p)
end = time.clock()
print(end - start)
```

**Update 2:**

The same, except with less multiplications and a `sum` function call:

```
sum_p = e_denom * sum([np.exp(-1j * p) for p in sums])
```

Comment: great! thanks a lot for all the input. I'm following up on each version. Will get back tomorrow!

Comment: ok, first question: in 

`for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
        sum_p += cmath.exp(-1j * (sum(r_p[j]) - sum(r_p[k])))`
there is no sum needed? as the generated inner product is already summed. ommitting this speeds this one already up by roughly factor 2

Comment: @joanwa - glad to hear that. I wanted to avoid vectorization because you said it made things worse, but if it works in combination with what I showed, that's great.

Comment: yeap, in your line `x * (p - q) = x1*p1 - x1*q1 + x2*p2 - x2*q2 - ...`, each `*` should represent a dot product with a scalar as a result. Hence your generation code's result should be of dimension `(N,1)` not `(N,3)`. And your code lines in Update I'm still trying to understand, as it gives me very different results. Will get back. Thanks a lot as I'm a lot closer already!

Comment: @joanwa - how different? Note that the imaginary part is very small, something around `e-13` for your code and `e-15` for my last version. That means they're actually identical for 13 digits. But if you can't use it for some reason, I'm not sure how to make it give the exact same result, sorry.

Comment: was a mistake on my side. Get the same errors as you do, after 10 or so digits they differ... which is completely fine

Comment: @joanwa - glad to hear. Added another update with a `sum` call - a pretty obvious simplification but I thought I'd add it in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That double loop is a time killer in `numpy`.  If you use vectorized array operations, the evaluation is cut to under a second.

```
In [1764]: sum_np=0

In [1765]: for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
       sum_np += np.exp(-1j * np.inner(x_np,(r_np[j] - r_np[k])))

In [1766]: sum_np
Out[1766]: (2116.3316526447466-1.0796252780664872e-11j)

In [1767]: np.exp(-1j * np.inner(x_np, (r_np[:N,None,:]-r_np[None,:N,:]))).sum((0,1))
Out[1767]: (2116.3316526447466-1.0796252780664872e-11j)
```

Timings:

```
In [1768]: timeit np.exp(-1j * np.inner(x_np, (r_np[:N,None,:]-r_np[None,:N,:]))).sum((0,1))
1 loops, best of 3: 506 ms per loop

In [1769]: %%timeit
sum_np=0
for j in range(0,N):
    for k in range(0,N):
       sum_np += np.exp(-1j * np.inner(x_np,(r_np[j] - r_np[k])))
1 loops, best of 3: 12.9 s per loop
```

replacing `np.inner` with `np.einsum` shaves 20% off the time

```
np.exp(-1j * np.einsum('k,ijk', x_np, r_np[:N,None,:]-r_np[None,:N,:])).sum((0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks a lot for the help. IVlads last code that uses the identity `sum_j sum_k a[j]*a[k] = sum_j a[j] * sum_k a[k]` makes the biggest difference. This now scales also with less then O(N^2).
Precalculating the dot product before the sum makes hpaulj's numpy suggestion exactly the same fast:

```
sum_np = 0
dotprods = np.inner(q_np,r_np)
sum_rkexp = np.exp(1j * dotprods).sum()
sum_np = sum_rkexp * np.exp(-1j * dotprods).sum()
```

both with a runtime about `0.0003s`. However, I found one more thing that gives another ~50% increase, instead of computing the exponential twice, I take the complex conjugate inside the sum:

```
sum_np = 0
dotprods = np.inner(q_np,r_np)
rkexp = np.exp(1j * dotprods)
sum_rkexp = rkexp.sum()
sum_np = sum_rkexp * np.conj(rkexp).sum()
```

which runs at around `0.0002s`. Over my first attempts with non vectorized numpy that took `~4s`, this is a speedup of about `2*10^4`, and for my 'real data' arrays of `N~6000` which run about `125s` I now get `0.0005s`, which is an amazing speedup of about `2.5*10^5`. Thanks a lot, IVlad and hpaulj, learned a lot in the last day :)
P.S. I'm amazed by how quick you guys answer with stuff that took me half a day to just follow up ;)

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting an answer (click the tick mark on top of it) and upvoting (click the up arrows) the answers that you found helpful.

Comment: I did, just upvoting I can't because I don't have enough reputation